# Texture paint not working on sculpt Blender 2.8

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, sculpting

So I have followed many tutorials on how to paint textures and it does work in simple objects, but not on a this sculpt. I can paint vertices and weight but not texture. I have tried to change to edit mode and back like suggested here: https://blenderartists.org/t/not-again-cannot-texture-paint-in-3d-viewport/532884 , no luck.

- I can't paint in 3D or UV
- I see the cursor I see my texture in the same color
- it is connected to the model
- I can flood fill and change
- the color of everything (again proving that the texture is linked)
- Mask is not activated
- my normals are correct (I can not paint inside or outside)

but the brush does nothing.

/edit: here is the file as requested
[image]
[image: Texture tab showing my settings]

Comment: could you share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots, Thank you for mentioning that. I have uploaded the file and attached it to the main post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a new way to paint in 2.8 but for the moment your object doesn't have any material, so create a basic node chain like *Image Texture* (with your "main Okulossos Paint" image loaded) > *Base Color* input of a *Principled BSDF* > *Material Output*.

Now you still won't be able to paint, it's because you've opened a completely black texture for your brush, so close it and you'll have access to the normal color palet:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I can't really figure out what you mean. I can't find the nodes you are talking about. I checked tutorials on this, but they also give no indication of how this is done. Could you give me a bit more information?

Comment: The nodes are in the Shader Editor window. You'll easily find tutorials on this topic, maybe for a former version of Blender but it hasn't changed a lot, example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YNxmh5UVi08  or  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FobUOuISak

Comment: ah, shader, got it. The icon looks very different in my version. that is why I could not find it.